Alternative to Headless JS
I am trying to write a React Native app that runs some processing every 15 minutes. To be specific: I want fetch a status from an open 3rd party API and create a notification if that status has changed.
I thought I could use a React Native module and Headless JS to do this:

Use a native module to create a Work Manager:

a. JS Side:
import { NativeModules } from "react-native";

const { WorkerModule } = NativeModules;

WorkerModule.configureWorker();

b. Native Side:
class WorkerModule(reactContext: ReactApplicationContext) : ReactContextBaseJavaModule(reactContext) {  
  
    var context = reactContext.getApplicationContext()  
  
    override fun getName() = "WorkerModule"  
  
    @ReactMethod fun configureWorker() {  
        val periodicRequest = PeriodicWorkRequest  
            .Builder(MyWorker::class.java, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)  
            .setInitialDelay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)  
            .build()  
  
        WorkManager  
            .getInstance(this.context)  
            .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("unique_work_name", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.UPDATE, periodicRequest)  
    }  
}



Register a javascript function with Headless JS (as per HeadlessJS docs)

a. JS Side:
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask("myBackgroundFetchFunction", (...args) => {
    console.log('woo! im a react native background javascript task')
    console.log('but i never get called - Booo!')
    // do my fetch and notification logic in javascript
});

b.  Native Side
class JsTaskService : HeadlessJsTaskService() {  
    override fun getTaskConfig(intent: Intent): HeadlessJsTaskConfig? {  
        return intent.extras?.let {  
            HeadlessJsTaskConfig(  
                "myBackgroundFetchFunction",  
                null,
                5000, // timeout for the task  
                true // optional: defines whether or not the task is allowed in foreground.  
                // Default is false            )  
        }  
    }  
}


Use a native worker to call my javascript function using Headless JS:

class MyWorker(context: Context, private val workParams: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, workParams) {  
    override fun doWork(): Result {  
        Log.d("MyWorker", "im a background task running in kotlin")
        val service = Intent(applicationContext, JsTaskService::class.java);  
  
        HeadlessJsTaskService.acquireWakeLockNow(applicationContext)  
    
        applicationContext.startForegroundService(service) 

        // or for older version of android:
        // applicationContext.startService(service) 
        return Result.success()  
    }  
}


Register the service in the AndroidManifest:

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
  ...
  <application 
      android:name=".MainApplication" 
      android:label="@string/app_name" 
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" 
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" 
      android:allowBackup="true" 
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
  >      
    ...    
    <service android:name=".....JsTaskService" />  
    <service        
        android:name="androidx.work.impl.foreground.SystemForegroundService"  
        android:foregroundServiceType="shortService" />  
  </application>
</manifest>

However on my device running Android 14 I'm getting errors when trying to run the line applicationContext.startForegroundService(service).
android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException: startForegroundService() not allowed due to mAllowStartForeground false

I understand that this is because on Android 14 it is no longer possible to start a foreground service from background services.
I have also seen that Headless JS is not being actively supported or recommended by the React Native team and is not used internally at Meta

Questions:

What alternatives do we have to run javascript code in the background of our React Native applications?
Are there any examples around that can be followed and allow javascript functions to run in the background of a React Native app on the latest versions of Android 14 SDK version 34+?


Workers are in the background, and background tasks can't generally start foreground tasks (there are some exceptions).  You shouldn't have a Service at all in this, you should just be doing whatever it is directly in your worker, without a Service.  But if you have to because the RN infrastructure won't work any other way, it shouldn't be a foreground service.
On a side note-  this is really not a great fit for ReactNative.  I'd strongly consider writing it natively, RN doesn't really mesh well with Android's background processing, and the startup time and memory costs are high for something hoping to run in the background and not get killed.  I think you can make it work, but it wouldn't be something I'd suggest.

You are probably right that it isn't a great fit for RN, but I guess I'm being lazy and I don't want to have to learn how to write an app natively when I already know React and Typescript pretty well. Especially as this is a side project.
